# how to grab text after newline

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep

###### assume this:

This is the only text I'M showing. The remaining text has more data[not showing], the problem. The text is semi-clean, full of whitespace, tabs, Unicode, isn't clean and has to be like this[my needs], so copy/paste this exact text doesn't work [formatted by markup]:

I have **SOME** text like this:

```
*** *
more text with spaces and  tabs                                                             
*****
1
Something here and else, 2000 edf, 60 pop
    Usd324.32           2 Usd534.22
2
21st New tetx that will like to select with pattern, 334 pop
    Usd162.14

*** *
more text with spaces and tabs, unicode
*****
```

I'm trying to grab this explicit text:

- `1 Something here and else, 2000 edf, 60 pop Usd324.32`

because of the `newline` and `whitespace`, the next command only grabs `1`:

```bsh
grep -E '1\s.+'
```

also, I have been trying to make it with new concats:

```
grep -E '1\s|[A-Z].+'
```

But doesn't work, `grep` begins to select similar pattern in different parts of the text

```bsh
awk '{$1=$1}1'   #done already
tr -s "\t\r\n\v" #done already
tr -d "\t\b\r"   #done already
```

How can I grab:

- grab 1 `newline`
- grab the whole second line after **1** `newline`
- grab the number `$Usd324.34` and remove `Usd`

Comment: do you want to do this just for lines containing **1**?  Or do you want to join and modify every group of three lines starting with a line containing only a number?

Comment: I rolled back your question to the original data. Please make sure to ask the question you need, once answers have been posted, if you change the input data that renders the answers useless. So please don't do that. If you made a mistake and the real data are too different, once answers have been posted, the best thing to do is ask a new question.

Comment: @terdon oh! Thank you, for bringing more confusion because people don't miss, be helpful

Comment: @AlexPixel I am trying to be helpful. Other people have already spent their time trying to help you so when you change the question, you make all of their work obsolete. Everyone here is a volunteer, so you need to help us help you. Please don't redefine a question after people have already answered. If you realize that isn't the question you actually wanted to ask, then please ask a new one. The existing answers work for the question you had posted, and the answers will be useful to the next, possibly thousands, of users who see this.

Comment: @terdon so the EDIT button shouldn't exist under YOUR logic, moderator re-change question and NOT taking the time to answer questions, waste of time, and creating bugs, so I should make 3 different questions that are the same, so other moderator comes and says "this questions it's a duplicate", because didn't take the time to read carefully the question, just for getting a ridiculous badge

Comment: No, the edit button should absolutely exist. But the problem is that when asking about parsing data, the specifics of the data are essential. When you change the data, any answers that had been posted about the original data become useless. Please do edit and improve your questions, that is great! Just don't change the input so that existing answers no longer work.

Comment: @terdon IM asking for my benefit, looking for an answer that works for ME, not the moderator, expectations, or because the answer that you think is working then is not going to work. And still not working

Answer (score 2):

`pcregrep` has a `M`ultiline mode and the ability to `o`utput the contents of capture groups:

```
$ pcregrep -Mo1 -o2 -o3 --om-separator ' ' '^(1)\n(.*)\n\h*Usd(\H+)' file
1 Something here and else, 2000 edf, 60 pop 324.32
```

Comment: This only works if the file is clean, and the text is only the above, but because I CAN'T change my question by @terdon standards, so this doesn't work for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

- To join and modify three lines starting from a line containing only "1" and optional whitespace:

```
$ perl -0777ne '/^1\s+(.*?)\h*\n\h*Usd(\H+)/imsg && printf "1 %s %s\n", $1, $2' input.txt
1 Something here and else, 2000 edf, 60 pop 324.32
```

The `-0777` option tells perl to read in the entire file at once, rather than one line at a time.  `-n` tells it to process its input similar to how `sed -n` would.  `-e` tells perl that the next argument is a script.

If the regular expression matches the text, it prints the text captured by the RE's capture groups in the desired format.

Matching the "optional trailing whitespace" is to deal with the fact that the sample file I copy-pasted from your question had trailing space characters on several lines.  I don't know if that's in your original file or if it's just an artifact of you pasting it into your question - doesn't matter, the script will work the same whether the trailing spaces are there or not.

- To join and modify any grouping of three lines beginning with a line containing only digit(s) and optional whitespace:

```
$ perl -n -e 'if (/^\d+\s*$/) {
     chomp; $_ .= " " . <>;
     chomp; $_ .= " " . <>;
     s/\s{2,}/ /g;
     s/Usd(\H+).*/$1/i;
     print
   }' input.txt
1 Something here and else, 2000 edf, 60 pop 324.32
2 21st New tetx that will like to select with pattern, 334 pop 162.14
```

Whenever a line contains only digit(s) with optional trailing whitespace, it gets the next two lines, appends them to the current line, then modifies and prints it.

The `chomp` strips the newline at the end of each line, and `<>` reads the next line of input. It does that twice to get and append the following two lines.  Then it modifies the joined line with two `s///` operations (the first reduces two or more whitespace characters to a single space, and the second removes everything from the line after the first "Usd\H+" while also removing the literal string "Usd".  This last operations is done case-insenstively) before printing it.

`\h` is perl regex for matching any horizontal whitespace character.  `\H` is the opposite, matching anything that **isn't** horizontal whitespace.

- Both of these perl one-liners work (and produce identical output) with both your original sample data AND the updated sample in your edited question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` like that:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {count = 0; ORS=" "} /^1$/ {found = 1; print; next; count++} found && count < 1 {count++; print; next} count == 1 {print $1; exit} END {printf "\n"}' < FILE
1 Something here and else, 2000 edf, 60 pop 324.32
```

Or using `getline()`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} /^1$/ {getline; print; getline; print $1} END {printf "\n"}' < FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` too can be good for that job:

```
sed -n '/^1 $/{h;n;H;n;s/^ *\([0-9.]*\).*/ \1/;H;g;s/\n//g;p}' sample
```